# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when building for ARM64

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, crypto++

I built the cryptopp lib to using for an ios application. but isn't working , only told me

> "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "CryptoPP::ProxyFilter::IsolatedFlush(bool, bool)", referenced from: "

and on and on...

and I follow the Crypopp wiki page's guideline, but it still crashing.

how can I fix that?

> ld: warning: ignoring file [path]/libcryptopp.a, missing required
>   architecture x86_64 in file [path]/libcryptopp.a (4
>   slices)CryptoPP::ProxyFilter::IsolatedFlush(bool, bool)", referenced
>   from: ... ... ... (118 things)

---

I tried to build with [github's prebuilt cryptopp](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios) but it doesn't work, too. it occur errors like below:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>    "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelFlush(std::string const&, bool, int, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long, std::string const&, bool) const", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, std::string const&, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelPut2(std::string const&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, int, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelCreatePutSpace(std::string const&, unsigned long&)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelPutModifiable2(std::string const&, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelMessageSeriesEnd(std::string const&, int, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::SetRetrievalChannel(std::string const&)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate::StringSinkTemplate(std::string&)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  encryptString(std::string const&) in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  decryptString(std::string const&, int) in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  MYCLASSAAA::setDeviceId() in MYCLASSAAA.o
>  MYCLASSAAA::getSignature() in MYCLASSAAA.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

the MYCLASSAAA and MYCLASSBBB are all of classes what using cryptopp lib.

I'll try to build the lib myself, but I think it maybe same errors happen. what I suppose to do?

and project settings -- I didn't changed "Compile Sources As" to Objective-C++ at "Apple LLVM 6.0 - language", I just setted that to "According to File Type". it must be objective-c++? when I change to that, it occur too many errors in another sources. because it is legacy project of cocos2d-x(0.12.0 / c++ project)...

I hope your help. thanks.

Comment: Did it occur both when running on simulator and devices?

Comment: @user523234 ya occur in any target

Comment: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" - it sounds like your application is being built for x86_64, and not an iOS architecture (like armv7 or arm64). What does `lipo` report for your library: `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libcryptopp.a`?

Comment: @jww iPhone 6 simulator is using the x86_64. I re-built that library with right settings, and ignoring file warnings are disappeared. but it still told me "undefined symbols for architecture x86_64".

Comment: @jww and my library is [ Architectures in the fat file: libcryptopp.a are: x86_64 i386 ]

Comment: @jaguar - also see [cryptopp-5.6.2-ios](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios) on Github. It has everything pre-built and packaged in a fat library. (Thanks for making me aware of x86_64 for ARM64 Simulator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this--- in short, it have to build with -stdlib=libstdc++ flag(to CXXFLAGS in GNUMAKEFILE) when building libcryptopp.

because my project is legacy cocos2d-x project, that's standard library is setted to libstdc++.

more infomation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28315574/3835380). jeffrey answered me about this in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I fix that?

Short answer: run  `. ./setenv-ios.sh x86_64` after downloading a new copy of the script. By default, `setenv-ios.sh` uses i386 for the simulator, and it did not support x86_64. The script now responds to x86_64, so fetch a new copy.

Based on @rmaddy's answer at [Does Xcode 6 Simulator use x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28079224/608639), it appears Xcode 6/iOS 8 SDK uses x86_64 for the simulator under some circumstances.

A new version of [`setenv-ios.sh`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/File:setenv-ios.sh.zip) was uploaded. It will respond to `. ./setenv-ios.sh x86_64` by selecting the `iPhoneSimulator.platform` SDK using `-arch x86_64` as a compiler option.

A new section covering this on the Crpyto++ wiki page for [iOS (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_%28Command_Line%29) was added. See the section *Simulators, ARM64 and x86_64*.

Comment: thank you for edit shell script. I'll try again and will reply this answer. and I'm sorry for too late check this answer.