# Undefined symbols in Crypto++/iOS 64-bit project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, crypto++

I tried to build with [github's prebuilt cryptopp](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios) but it doesn't work, too. it occur errors like below:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>    "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelFlush(std::string const&, bool, int, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long, std::string const&, bool) const", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::Filter::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, std::string const&, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelPut2(std::string const&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, int, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelCreatePutSpace(std::string const&, unsigned long&)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelPutModifiable2(std::string const&, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelMessageSeriesEnd(std::string const&, int, bool)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::SetRetrievalChannel(std::string const&)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Base64Decoder in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Unflushable<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
> ```
>
> "CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate::StringSinkTemplate(std::string&)", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  encryptString(std::string const&) in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  decryptString(std::string const&, int) in MYCLASSBBB.o
>  MYCLASSAAA::setDeviceId() in MYCLASSAAA.o
>  MYCLASSAAA::getSignature() in MYCLASSAAA.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

the MYCLASSAAA and MYCLASSBBB are all of classes what using cryptopp lib.
it using cryptlib.h, modes.h, filters.h, aes.h, base64.h, md5.h, hex.h.

I even tried to build the lib myself, but I it same errors happen. what should I do?

I hope your help. thanks.

---

add the xcode cmd

> Ld /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-aknkujyaqvqjswbhspmawywtyqee/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/PROJECT_NAME.app/PROJECT_NAME normal arm64
>       cd /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Development/Office_Projects/PROJECTROOT/root
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-aknkujyaqvqjswbhspmawywtyqee/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Development/Office_Projects/PROJECTROOT/root/PROJECT_NAME/libs/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/ios/libraries -L/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Development/Office_Projects/PROJECTROOT/root/PROJECT_NAME/libs/EEAF-SDK7.0(i386,armv7,armv7s,arm64) -L/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Development/Office_Projects/PROJECTROOT/root/PROJECT_NAME/libs/boost_1_57/ios -L/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Development/Office_Projects/PROJECTROOT/root/PROJECT_NAME/Classes/cryptopp/lib -LPROJECT_NAME/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/ios/libraries -LPROJECT_NAME/EEAF-SDK7.0(i386,armv7,armv7s,arm64) -F/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-aknkujyaqvqjswbhspmawywtyqee/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Development/Office_Projects/PROJECTROOT/root/PROJECT_NAME/libs -filelist /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-aknkujyaqvqjswbhspmawywtyqee/Build/Intermediates/PROJECT_NAME.build/Release-iphoneos/PROJECT_NAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PROJECT_NAME.LinkFileList -dead_strip -lxml2 -lz -ObjC -lcryptopp -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.1.1 -lc++ /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Development/Office_Projects/PROJECTROOT/root/PROJECT_NAME/libs/boost_1_57/ios/boost.a -framework UIKit -framework CoreTelephony -lEEAF -framework FacebookSDK -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework ImageIO -framework MediaPlayer -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3.0 -framework StoreKit -lcurl -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-aknkujyaqvqjswbhspmawywtyqee/Build/Intermediates/PROJECT_NAME.build/Release-iphoneos/PROJECT_NAME.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PROJECT_NAME_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-aknkujyaqvqjswbhspmawywtyqee/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/PROJECT_NAME.app/PROJECT_NAME

and "vtable for CRYPTOPP::~.o" always happen. with a notice :

> NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

Comment: "I even tried to build the lib myself" - and you did that *how* ? A search for your title text *verbatim* resulted in several potential reasons, one of which shows [some promise](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/fh1Fhdcn-Rw/3eP1NOxBfAkJ).

Comment: @WhozCraig well, I built that lib with "build-for-ios.sh" in [here](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios) /setenv-ios.sh is updated as [this](http://www.cryptopp.com/w/images/a/ab/Setenv-ios.sh.zip).

Comment: @Jaguar what is there in Build setting > under Architectures ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelFlush(std::string const&, bool, int, bool)", referenced from:

 vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleProxyFilter in MYCLASSBBB.o
 vtable for CryptoPP::Bufferless<CryptoPP::Filter> in MYCLASSBBB.o
```

I *think* you are *not* using `libc++`, which is LLVM's C++ standard library. I think that because I don't see a `-stdlib=libc++` (but I don't recall if that's passed to `ld` directly).

The symbol is defined in the [github's prebuilt cryptopp](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios) (that's my github, btw). Here's how to verify.

First, extract the arm64 library from the fat library:

```
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo libcryptopp.a -thin arm64 -output libcryptopp-arm64.a
$ ls
libcryptopp-arm64.a libcryptopp.a
```

Next, use `nm` to dump global symbols, and use `c++filt` to demangle:

```
$ nm -g libcryptopp-arm64.a | c++filt | grep BufferedTransformation::ChannelFlush | grep " T "
0000000000002110 T CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelFlush(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, int, bool)
```

The capitol `T` means you are searching for symbols that are defined and exported. Lower `t` means its defined *but* not exported - i.e., private. Capitol `U` means its undefined.

The `__1` is what `libc++` (LLVM) uses to differentiate from `libstdc++` (GNU). `std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >` is a `string`, so that could be rewritten as:

```
CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelFlush(std::__1::string const&, bool, int, bool)
```

*If* this library was built against `libstdc++` (GNU), then the symbol from the library would be:

```
CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelFlush(std:::string const&, bool, int, bool)
```

We can repeat for the second problem child, and it follows the same pattern (`libc++`, and not `libstdc++`):

```
$ nm -g libcryptopp-arm64.a | c++filt | grep CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2 | grep " T "
00000000000001c4 T CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
CryptoPP::Filter::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long, std::__1::string const&, bool) const
```

### -----

*IF* you need GNU's `libstdc++`, then you can build it yourself. Here are the steps:

1. Download and unpack Crypto++ from the website
2. Download and unpack [`cryptopp-mobile.zip`](http://www.cryptopp.com/w/images/a/a0/Cryptopp-mobile.zip). Unpack it right over top the Crypto++ source files
3. Open the new `GNUmakefile`, find the iOS rule by searching for the block that begins with `IS_IOS`
4. Change this line in the `IS_IOS` block: `CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++`. Change it to `CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libstdc++`
5. Do the cross compile...

### -----

I downloaded Cocos2D-x and tried to look at its configuration (I'm not a Cmake guy, so I could be wrong with what follows). It has the following in `CmakeList.txt`:

```
if(MSVC)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
                  -wd4251 -wd4244 -wd4334 -wd4005 -wd4820 -wd4710
                  -wd4514 -wd4056 -wd4996 -wd4099)
else()
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -Wall -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG})
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fno-exceptions -std=c99")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-exceptions -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-reorder")
  if(CLANG)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
  endif()
endif(MSVC)
```

*If* Cmake is doing what I suspect, then its using LLVM's `libc++`. But its also using `-std=c++11`, and the GitHub project is not using it. But I'm not sure `-std=c++11` makes a difference here.

Just bike shedding, but this is a bad sign: `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. If they are blatantly doing that, then they probably have various degrees of of badness and brokenness. (Just my experience with auditing software).

---

If interested, the `__1` is an inline namespace used for versioning. See [What are inline namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11016220) and [Where does the __1 symbol come from when using LLVM's libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29293394).

Comment: thanks a lot! actually I solved this with [your help in mailing archive](http://cryptopp-users.narkive.com/EvC1yG41/can-t-connect-cryptopp-to-surespot-app-please-help)! it works very fine, I appreciate your help. have a nice day!